# Show that the least squares line must pass through the center of mass

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

My problem:

> The point $(\bar x, \bar y)$ is the *center of mass* for the collection of points in Exercise 7. Show that the least squares line must pass through the center of mass. [*Hint*: Use a change of variables $z = x - \bar x$ to translate the problem so that the new independent variable has mean 0.]

I have already solved Exercise 7:

> Given a collection of points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$, let $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^T$, $\mathbf y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)^T$, $\bar x = \frac 1n \sum_1^n x_i$, $\bar y = \frac 1n \sum_1^n y_i$ and let $y = c_0 + c_1 y$ be the linear function that gives the best least squares fit to the points. Show that if $\bar x = 0$, then $c_0 = \bar y$ and $c_1 = \frac {\mathbf x^T \mathbf y}{\mathbf x^T \mathbf x}$.

It is obvious that if $x = \bar x$ then $y = c_0 + c_1x = \bar y + 0 = \bar y$, however the hint suggests that the problem should be solved in another way.

**Edit**
I have found an answer. It makes use of the following theorem:

> If A is an *m* x *n* matrix of rank *n*, the normal equations $ A^T A \mathbf x = A^T \mathbf b$ have a unique solution $ \hat {\mathbf x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T \mathbf b$ and $ \hat {\mathbf x} $ is the unique least squares solution of the system $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf b $.

Now let $ \hat {\mathbf x} = \mathbf c = (c_0, c_1)^T, A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1 \\x_1 & \cdots & x_n \\\end{pmatrix}, \mathbf b = \mathbf y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)^T $ such that $c = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}n & \sum x_i\\\sum x_i & \sum x_i^2\\\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}\sum y_i\\\sum x_iy_i\\\end{pmatrix} $$
which gives values for $c_0$ and $c_1$. These values should be used in the formula $c_1x + c_0$, which, together with $ x = \bar x = \frac 1n \sum x_i$, indeed results in $ \bar y $.

Comment: They gave you the hint. Rewrite the problem using z instead of x.

Answer (score 6):

Assume we have the linear model
$$y=X\beta$$
where
\begin{align*}
y_{n\times1} =\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{2cm}
X_{n\times2} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1\\
1& x_2\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{2cm}
\beta_{2\times1} = \begin{bmatrix}
b_0\\
b_1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*} 
and so using linear algebra we have (all of my sums are with respect to $i$ and go to $n$, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n$) 
\begin{align*}
\beta  &= (X'X)^{-1}X'y\\
&=\left( \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1&\cdots & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1\\
1& x_2\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1&\cdots & 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\left(\begin{bmatrix}
n&\sum x_i\\
\sum  x_i & \sum x_i^2
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
\sum  y_i\\
\sum x_iy_i
\end{bmatrix}\\
& \hspace{-1.45in}\text{taking the inverse is not hard since it is a }2\times2 \text{ matrix}\\
&=\frac{1}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum  x_i\right)^2}\begin{bmatrix}
\sum  x_i^2 & -\sum x_i\\
 -\sum x_i & n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\sum  y_i\\
\sum x_iy_i
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
\frac{n\sum x_iy_i-\sum x_i\sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and so,
\begin{align*}
b_0 = \frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
b_1 = \frac{n\sum x_iy_i-\sum x_i\sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}
\end{align*}

Now we have $b_0$ and $b_1$ and so for any value of $x$ we can figure out the corresponding $y$ value.  The cool thing about the least squares line is that it WILL ALWAYS pass through the point that corresponds to the mean of $x$ and the mean of $y$. Why is that true?  Plug in $\bar x$ to $y=b_0+b_1x$ and after some algebra it's easy to see.

Let's plug in $\bar x$ for $x$ in $y=b_0+b_1x$, so

\begin{align*}
b_0+b_1\bar x &=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}+\frac{n\sum x_iy_i-\sum x_i\sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\times\frac{1}{n}\sum x\\
&=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}+\frac{n\sum x_iy_i\sum x_i-\sum x_i\sum y_i\sum x_i}{n^2\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}+\frac{\sum x_iy_i\sum x_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}-\frac{\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\sum y_i}{n^2\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\sum x_i\sum x_iy_i+\sum x_iy_i\sum x_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}-\frac{\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\sum y_i}{n^2\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}-\frac{\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\sum y_i}{n^2\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sum x_i^2\sum y_i-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sum y_i\left(\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2\right)}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i\\
&\bar y
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass property
$$
\bar{y} = c_{0} + c_{1} \bar{x}
$$
stems from the fact that one of the free parameters corresponds to a constant term.

Define the residual error as the difference between the data and the prediction:
$$
  r_{k} = y_{k} - c_{0} - c_{1} x_{k}.
$$
The least squares solution finds the parameters $c,$ which minimize the residual sum of squares given by
$$
  r^{2}(c) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( y_{k} - c_{0} - c_{1} x_{k} \right)^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} r_{k}^{2},
$$
Canonical minimization creates the equation
$$
 \frac{\partial} {\partial c_{0}} r^{2} = \frac{\partial} {\partial c_{0}} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( y_{k} - c_{0} - c_{1} x_{k} \right)^{2} = -2\sum_{k=1}^{m} r_{k} = 0.
$$
Therefore, *the sum of the residuals must be* 0, which implies the sum of the residuals is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m} r_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( y_{k} - c_{0} - c_{1} x_{k} \right) = 0.
$$
Now, divide through by $m$, the number of measurements:
$$
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( y_{k} - c_{0} - c_{1} x_{k} \right) = 0,
$$
and rearrange terms to recover
$$
\bar{y} = c_{0} + c_{1} \bar{x}.
$$

Again, this a general answer which holds for any trial function like
$$
y(x) = c_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^{d} f_{k}(x)
$$
where the $d$ functions $f_{k}(x)$ are a linear independent set with addition of the constant vector.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the least squares line must pass through the center of mass, one does not need to invert the Gram matrix $A^TA.$

Instead, we start from
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{0} \\
c_{1}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} y_{i}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is equivalent to $A^{T}Ac = A^{T}y$ and is derivable from geometry. Next, we focus on the first equation in the system of linear equations, which is also known as the normal equations. Namely, we rewrite the first equation:
$$nc_{0} + (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i})c_{1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}$$
in terms of the center of mass entries:
$$nc_{0} + n\bar{x}c_{1} = n\bar{y}.$$
After dividing by $n,$ we obtain $c_{0} + \bar{x}c_{1} = \bar{y},$ which is the desired conclusion.