# Least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, mean-square-error

Let $\\A$ be a matrix of size $\\(m, n)$, $\\b$ a column vector of size $\\m$, $\\x$ a column vector of size $\\n$ and $\\a$ a real number.

If $\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}$ is the least-squares solution to the linear matrix equation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A &  \begin{matrix}
-1 \\ 
-1 \\
... \\ 
-1 
\end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
a
\end{bmatrix} = b
$$

does it mean that the arithmetic mean of $\\A x - b$ equals $\\a$?

As background information, I used that result to answer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909414/loops-to-minimize-function-of-arrays-in-python/) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is $b$ a column vector whose entries are all the scalar value $b$?

Comment: It is a column vector, but the values can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is actually a restatement of the following well-known fact: if the design matrix contains a column of all ones (or equivalently, all negative-ones), then the sum of the residuals is zero. For a short proof, 
let $e$ denote the column of all ones, $X = [A, -e]$, by the nature of least squares, the residual vector $b - (Ax - ae)$ is perpendicular to the linear space spanned by the columns of $X$. In particular, it is perpendicular to the vector $e$, thus,
$$0 = e^T(b - Ax + ae) = an - e^T(Ax - b)$$
or $a = e^T(Ax - b)/n$, which is your assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to derive the answer based upon the calculus of minimization is given in [Show that the least squares line must pass through the center of mass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635670/show-that-the-least-squares-line-must-pass-through-the-center-of-mass).