# Let ${(x_i, y_i)}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of points in $R^2$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let ${(x_i, y_i)}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of points in $R^2$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0.$$ Consider the values of $\alpha, \beta$ which minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha x_i + \beta - y_i|^2$$ (the linear least squares fit). Show that $\beta$ = 0.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried and what do you know (for instance it's important that we know to give an answer at your desired level)?

Comment: Hi, well I've been reading my textbook over and over again, and it says that if we are in R^n, we can forget about absolute values and take partial derivatives and find where all of them are 0. I don't know if this can be applied here or not?

Comment: Another perspective: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635670/show-that-the-least-squares-line-must-pass-through-the-center-of-mass/2170960#2170960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\displaystyle f(\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha x_i + \beta - y_i)^2$ then
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\alpha}=0,\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\beta}=0.
\end{cases}

Comment: Thank you! I began with this and I believe I've got it from here :) I appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want, you can write your answer in the answer box, perhaps be useful for others.